# Return MAX value with VLOOKUP from list

Tags: google-sheets, max, vlookup

I have a Google sheet with data of different players attacks and their corresponding damage.

**Sheet1**

```
| Player      | Attack      | Damage      |
|:------------|:-----------:|------------:|
| Iron Man    | Melee       | 50          |
| Iron Man    | Missile     | 2500        |
| Iron Man    | Unibeam     | 100         |
| Superman    | Melee       | 9000        |
| Superman    | Breath      | 200         |
| Superman    | Laser       | 1500        |
```

In my second sheet, I want to list each player and display their best attack and the corresponding damage. Like this:

**Sheet2**

```
| Player      | Best attack | Damage      |
|:------------|:-----------:|------------:|
| Iron Man    | Missile     | 2500        |
| Superman    | Melee       | 9000        |
```

I have tried to add the following in the damage column (third column) of Sheet2:
 `=MAX(IF(Sheet1!A:A=A2;Sheet1!C:C))`

But I get *9000* for Superman and *0* for Iron Man. For best attack (second column) I guess MAX should be used together with VLOOKUP, but I don't know how to apply it.

Edit:

`=ArrayFormula(MAX(IF(Sheet1!A:A=A3;Sheet1!C:C)))` seems to fix the first issue. Getting correct values in the damage column (third column). But still don't know how to apply this to return which is the best attack.

Comment: that is an array formula so it need to be wrapped in `ArrayFormula(...)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks, worked flawlessly - updated the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Filter.

Damage:

```
=MAX(FILTER(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A=A2))
```

Then Best Attack:

```
=JOIN(",",FILTER(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=A2,Sheet1!C:C=C2))
```

The Join will join two or more if there are more attacks with the same damage.

[image]

Comment: Works just as described. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

I am considering the range A2:C.

Try this formula.

```
=sortn(sort(A2:C,3,0),9^9,2,1,0)
```

Screenshot

[image]